# Python multithreading from multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

This is a sample demo of how I want to use threading.

```
import threading
import time

def run():
    print("started")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("ended")


thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
thread.start()

for i in range(4):
    print("middle")
    time.sleep(1)
```

How can I make this threading work demo even from multiple files?

Example:

```
# Main.py 
import background

""" Here I will have a main program and \
I want the command from the background file to constantly run. \
Not just once at the start of the program """
```

The second file:

```
# background.py

while True:
    print("This text should always be printing \
        even when my code in the main function is running")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all the lines before your `for` loop in `background.py`.  When it is imported it will start the thread running.  Change the `run` method to do your infinite `while` loop.

You may also want to set `daemon=True` when starting the thread so it will exit when the main program exits.

#### main.py

```
import time
import background
for i in range(4):
    print("middle")
    time.sleep(1)
```

#### background.py

```
import threading
import time

def run():
    while True:
        print("background")
        time.sleep(.5)

thread = threading.Thread(target=run,daemon=True)
thread.start()
```

#### Output

```
background
middle
background
middle
background
background
background
middle
background
background
middle
background
background
```